# Sitecore 60 day trial

Tags: licensing

I'm trying to use the Sitecore 60 day free trial, however I'm unable to download anything as it says I need to be Developer Certified in order to download. Any suggestions what I can do? Trying to get Sitecore running in Docker so myself and a few others can try it out with JSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Community site says "Once the request is approved, the developer is provided access to download software from dev.sitecore.net." ( https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/announcing-the-global-availability-of-the-sitecore-developer-trial )

Comment: Please contact developertrial@sitecore.com if you have access issues so the team can help you.